# Issue with function signature

Tags: haskell

I am writing a function which, taken a list, checks to see if all elements in it are in another list exactly one time. My attempt:

```
cA = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] {- original list -}

validate :: [Char] -> Bool
validate (n:[]) = if length (filter n cA) == 1 then True else False
validate (n:m) = if length (filter n cA) == 1 then validate m else False
```

Returning

Type error in application
*** Expression     : filter n cA**
 Term           : n
 **Type           : Char
*** Does not match : Char -> Bool

Ideas?

Comment: `filter n cA` requires `n` to be a function, but you provided a `Char`. You could do that by replacing `n` with `(==n)`.

Comment: Lost you there, what is (==n)?

Comment: `(==n)` is a section of `m==n` - the same as `(==) m n`. Here `(==)` is a function of two arguments, so `(==n)` is a function of one argument, which, given a `m` produces `True`, if `m==n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, pet peeve, if you ever see yourself writing

```
if foo then True else False
```

Stop and just write

```
foo
```

Second, the type of `n` is `Char` right? But filter is expecting `Char -> Bool`. So that's your error. I believe you want

```
validate [n] = length (filter (==n) cA) == 1
validate (n:ns) = length (filter (==n) cA) == 1 && validate ns
```

The `(==n)` is the same as `\a -> a == n`. This is called an operator section, it's just some good old Haskell sugar.

Oh and this can be written using the function `all`

```
validate ns = all (\n -> length (filter (==n) cA) == 1) ns
validate' = all $ (==1) . length . flip filter cA . (==)
```

Comment: Thanks! :D That worked! Just another question, is there some neat way of including a check in the function to see if the length of the two lists are equal?

Comment: @DarioP What two list?

Comment: The cA list which is used to call "filter" and the original list given as a paramter of the validate function

Comment: @DarioP In the recursive function it's tricky, since `validate` will be called with all the tails of the original list, in the `all` version, simply add `length ns == length cA && ...`

Comment: @DarioP The one at the bottom `validate ns = length ns == length cA && all ...`